# UIActivityIndicatorView hidden property is set to YES by default

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I just had an issue where a UIActivityIndicatorView object would not appear on the view.

In the docs, I found that it is set to NO/false by default.
However, I try to print the UIActivityIndicatorView object, and I see it is set to YES, which is the reason it was not visible.

Is this a bug, or just a small change in iOS 8 SDK, and the previous versions?

Comment: make sure your activityindicator is on top of layer and setHidden false.

Comment: I actually add it on top of an UIImageView, which resides in a cell. Even if I manually set: "imageLoadingActivityIndicator?.hidden = false" and "imageLoadingActivityIndicator?.startAnimating()" inside "override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)", it seems that once I scroll a bit, the hidden property is set to true by the system, and the animation is stopped. So my solution is to do that inside "override func layoutSubviews()".

Comment: Can you write your code here?
 so May be I can help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation,`UIActivityIndicatorView` has a property `hidesWhenStopped`. It is set to yes/true by default. Also this will be true when animation is stopped or animation is not started. So  when you are adding a `UIActivityIndicatorView`, you have to start animation.Also its good if set hidden property to false.